# Format CSV so it columns paste into cells in Microsoft excel

Tags: excel, csv

Where can I find out how to format my CSV so it can be pasted into excel, and automatically goes into cells?

I'm generating CSV, and I'm sure I have seen data that can be copied as CSV and pasted straight into cells without needing to go through the menu.

I've tried simple comma and tab seperation, and quoted cells but each row pastes in a single cell.

See image for more info:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is Tabbed delimited.

The longer answer that explains why your attempt to do tab delimited probably failed is... When you open excel and paste in something that isn't tab delimited you will paste it all in the same cell. So you went to Text-To-Columns and separated by hand. Now the delimiter you used in the Text-To-Columns dialog is now the default delimiter for the remainder of your Excel Session. You then pasted in Tabbed delimited and... it pasted it in a single cell again.

Try this

1. Make a tab delimited record, or file.
2. Close excel all the way and reopen it.
3. Copy and paste from the tab delimited file into your excel.
4. 
5. Profit.